# Why does python's bisect_left return a valid index even if the value does not exist?

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-search, bisection

I want to find if a number exists in a sorted array. To be straight an array contains fibonaccci number from 1 to 63. Below is the fibonacci number generator and some of it's output.

```
stacksize = 10000  # default 128 stack
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(stacksize)
def nthfibonacci(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return 1
    elif n == 2:
        return 1
    elif n > 2:
        return nthfibonacci(n - 2) + nthfibonacci(n - 1)

 output = [nthfibonacci(k) for k in range(1,63+1)]

 # truncated output: [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610,987, 
           1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946, 17711, 28657, 46368,.....]
```

Now I want to find if **number 7** exists or not so I used the following code
using python [bisection module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html):

```
from bisect import bisect_left
elem_index = bisect_left(a=output, x=7, lo=0, hi=len(arr) - 1) 
# output of elem_index is 5 ???? But it is expected to be len(output)+1, right?   
# as we know if element is not found it returns len(array)+1
```

Again if I just write a simple binary search it gives me correct result as follows:

```
def binsearch(arr, key):
    # arr.sort()
    low = 0
    high = len(arr) - 1
    while low <= high:
        mid = (low + high) // 2
        if arr[mid] == key:
            return mid
        else:
            if arr[mid] < key:
                low = mid + 1
            else:
                high = mid - 1
    return -1

print(binsearch(arr, 7)) # it gives me -1 as expected
```

**So what is happening?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation on `bisect_left`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left) explains the behaviour:

> ```
> bisect_left(...)
>     bisect_left(a, x[, lo[, hi]]) -> index
>
>     Return the index where to insert item x in list a, assuming a is sorted.
> ```

**In short, `bisect_left` (and `bisect_right`) tells you where an element is if it exists, or where to insert it if it doesn't.**

Consider a contrived example. Let's search for a value in a sorted list when that value exists.

```
l = [1, 4, 5]
bisect.bisect_left(l, 4)
# 1
```

`bisect_left` returns 1 because `l[1]` is `4`. Now, repeat the process, but with a value that does not exist in that list.

```
bisect.bisect_left(l, 3)
# 1
```

In this case, `l[1]` is where you would find 3 *if it existed* in that sorted list.

---

**What does this mean for you?** All you have do to is modify your function to query the element at the index returned by `bisect_left`,

```
def binary_search(items, key):
    idx = bisect_left(items, key)
    if items[idx] != key:
         return -1

    return idx
```

Comment: Totally make sense now. So we can do if arr[bisect_result] != key: print("Not Found"). Right @cs95?

Comment: the last suggestion will throw an exception if `key` is greater than any value in `items`

Answer (score 2):

As already noted, [`bisect_left()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left) just *locates the insertion point* for an element in a list to maintain sorted order. The documentation also [shows](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#searching-sorted-lists) how to transform `bisect_*` functions to actual lookups, so you could use:

```
def index(lst, elem):
    i = bisect_left(lst, elem)
    if i != len(lst) and lst[i] == elem:
        return i
    return -1
```